# Visual Studio Code on Windows: How can I pass command line arguments using launch.json?

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

From the windows command line, I can successfully call my script as follows:

```py
python spot_check.py "stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3" "stop|14   ST_ARRIVAL|2.6" "19:06:28" "19:15:00"
```

However, if I want to use the VS Code debugger, and I pass the same arguments using the `args` attribute in launch.json

```java
"args": [
    "stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3", 
    "stop|14   ST_ARRIVAL|2.6" ,
    "19:06:28",
    "19:15:00",
]
```

Then I get the following error:

```
(base) c:\Users\1266143\Desktop\stringlines_ml>cd c:\Users\1266143\Desktop\stringlines_ml && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && C:\Users\1266143\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\1266143\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 61850 c:\Users\1266143\Desktop\stringlines_ml\spot_check.py "stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3" "stop|14   ST_ARRIVAL|2.6" 19:06:28 19:15:00"
'CHST' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The part that reads `'CHST' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` leads me to believe that the `|` is being interpreted as a redirect, rather than as a character in a string literal argument, and the space following `CHST` means `CHST` is being interpreted as a command. But why would these arguments evaluate differently on the command line than in Visual Studio? How can I ensure that these arguments are passed correctly to my command line application when in debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### These aren't the quotes you're looking for

You require quotes around your arguments, as shown when running the script/program directly on the command-line (i.e. `"stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3"`)

But in the JSON, the first set of quotes will get stripped off when the JSON is interpreted, so the string `"stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3"` in the JSON becomes just `stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3` before it's fed to later processes.

Then all the arguments get fed to the Command Line or Python interpreter, which will look something like this (although it will likely be a huge line with a bunch of debugging flags and such):

```sh
c:/mypath/myfile stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3 stop|14   ST_ARRIVAL|2.6 19:06:28 19:15:00
```

The quotes you thought you had around the arguments no longer exist. This means that the parser interprets the vertical bar symbol as the "Pipe" command, which tell it that the first command is done, and it should take the output of that command and "pipe" it to the command that follows.

So, the parser thinks you told it to:

1. Run the command `c:/mypath/myfile stop`
2. Take the output of that command and pipe it to the command `CHST SQ_ARRIVAL`
3. Pipe the output of that command to the command `2.3 stop`
4. etc.

Since it can't find the command `CHST` with the argument `SQ_ARRIVAL`, it gives you the error message you are seeing.

---

### The fix is in

If you want the quotes to end up being passed along as a part of the argument you'll need to layer them. How to do this depends on how the JSON interpreter will handle multiple sets of quotes (I'm not sure how it does).

A few things to try:

1. Use triple quotes: `"""stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3"""` - in some parsers, when it sees the first quote it starts a string, but if it sees 2 quotes in a row after that, it makes them into a quote inside the string, rather than ending it. So the first and last quote start and end the string, while the other two pairs of quotes will be condensed into a quote on the outside of your argument
2. Use a backslash in front of the quotes inside the JSON string: `"\"stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3\""` - in many parsers the backslash character is an "escape" character and any character immediately after it is considered a string literal that will be put directly into the string, even if it is normally a special character.
3. Use single quotes inside the string: `"'stop|CHST SQ_ARRIVAL|2.3'"` - Since Python can use either single or double quotes as a string, normally any arguments going to a python interpreter with single quotes will also be considered a string. However, I'm not sure the arguments will get that far in this case, they will probably be interpreted by the shell first, which likely will not consider single quotes to be the start of a string (but you never know for sure..).

Which method works may depend on what shell you are using (i.e. Windows command prompt, Powershell, Git Bash, sh, c-sh, etc.). Each of them could handle command line interpretation of strings differently.

If none of these works, knowing the root cause, a further search should turn up the answer.  Good luck!